# Django include the same variables in all views

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I want to include the same variables in all the views , to avoid repeating , i've been looking at django docs and found the generic display views and i tried it but it doesnt seems to work.
Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: You can use template context processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

```
def add_foo(request):
    return {'var': 'foo'}
```

Save this to a file, lets say `custom_context.py`, put it inside the same directory as your `views.py`.

Then, add it to your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) - make sure you keep the default ones, otherwise other functions may not work.  You need to add the Python path, so add `yourapp.custom_context.add_foo,`

Now, whenever you return a `RequestContext` instance (you can do this by using the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render), and all class based views automatically return a `RequestContext` instance); the variable `var` will be available in your templates, as `{{ var }}`.

Comment: View is not Template in django (MVT).